# Problemas con Lazysizes (solo en imágenes dinámicas!)

Tags: javascript

¡Hola! Estoy implementando lazysizes y con imágenes estáticas funciona perfectamente para mí, pero cuando lo uso con imágenes dinámicas no funciona para mí.

Funciona:

```
<img class="lazyload" data-src="{{asset('img/minus.png')}}"/>
```

No funciona:

```
 @foreach($product_all->product_images as $i=>$product_image_all)
                <a href="{{route('product.detail', ['brand' => $product_all->brand, 'name' => $product_all->name])}}">
                    <img id="image-{{$product_all->id}}" class="lazyload" data-src="{{url('product/'.$product_image_all->image)}}">
                    @endforeach
```

¿Dónde está el problema?

EDIT: el codigo para obtener las imagenes

```
public function getImage($filename) {
        $file = \Storage::disk('products')->get($filename);

        return new Response($file, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Revisa el código fuente en el navegador (o usa el inspector) para asegurar que la ruta es correcta.

Comment: Sí, las imágenes cargan perfectamente. El caso es que no sé cómo hacer que Lazysizes funcionen con imágenes dinámicas, con imágenes estáticas funciona a la perfección

Comment: PD: la consola no me muestra ningún error

Comment: Con esta frase _"Sí, las imágenes cargan perfectamente"_ contradices toda la pregunta. Haz una prueba, agregando una imagen normal: `<img id="image-{{$product_all->id}}" src="{{url('product/'.$product_image_all->image)}}">`, si no carga, entonces el problema es con la ruta.

Comment: Ya hice la prueba añadiendo una imagen estática y funcionaba pero al llamar al foreach y recorrer mi array de imágenes de la base de datos no me funciona, qué puede ser? no tengo ni idea. Me muestra las imágenes tanto con src con con data-src pero aunque le aplique la clase lazyload no me hace la imagen lazy...

Comment: Mañana pruebo a quitar el enlace que engloba la img y meterla sola y te digo...

Comment: Hola @Triby lo he vuelto a probar (también usando loading="lazy" y en imagenes estáticas si me  funciona, en las dinámicas no. no se que puede fallar en la ruta... Edit con el método para obtener las imagenes

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.

Tenía arriba de este foreach otro que mostraba las mismas imagenes, y al ya cargarlas arriba no podia "recargarlas" porque ya estaban cargadas

Comment: ¿Cómo sería la solución en español y con código?

Comment: era tal como lo tenía